# scipy.stats.norm density function does not integrate to 1

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I was trying to use Monte-Carlo integration on the probability density function generated by scipy.stats.norm for the standard normal distribution and it converges to 1/(2*sqrt(pi)) instead of 1.

the code:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
from numpy import average, pi
import math
samples = norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=10000000)
average(norm.pdf(samples, loc=0, scale=1)) - (1/(2*math.sqrt(pi)))
```

This will return ~ 0.
Can someone please explain why it does not converge to 1. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are evaluating the PDF at a large, normally distributed sample, and then taking the average of those PDF values.  In effect, you are computing the expected value of the normal PDF with respect to the normal distribution.  Here's a quick way to calculate that:

```
In [284]: from scipy.stats import norm

In [285]: norm.expect(norm.pdf)
Out[285]: 0.28209479177387786

In [286]: 1/(2*np.sqrt(np.pi))
Out[286]: 0.28209479177387814
```

Comment: Silly me... You are right of course. I should have integrated against Lebesgue measure (using Rimann sums for example). This indeed returns 1.